# Finding the real roots of a radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$x$=  $\sqrt{x-\frac 1x}$ + $\sqrt{1-\frac 1x}$

What are the real roots?

Comment: In cases like this, and *after* answers have been posted, it may be a better idea to ask a new question rather than radically changing the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ *EDIT* ] *Original hint remains in the edit history, the following applies to the re-edited question*.

> $$x =  \sqrt{x-\frac 1x} + \sqrt{1-\frac 1x} \tag{1}$$

Taking the inverses on both sides (since $x\ne0\,$):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x} & = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} + \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}} \;\cdot\; \cfrac{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}} \\[3pt]
 & = \cfrac{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}}{\left(x-\cancel{\frac{1}{x}}\right) - \left(1-\cancel{\frac{1}{x}}\right)} = \cfrac{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}}{x-1}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\iff\quad\;\; \cfrac{x-1}{x} = \sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}
 \tag{2}
$$

Subtracting $(1)-(2)$ gives:

$$
x - \frac{x-1}{x} = 2 \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}} \;\;\iff\;\; x - 1 + \frac{1}{x} = 2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x}} \tag{3}
$$

Multiplying by $x\,$, squaring, and noting that the equation becomes of the form $(a+1)^2=4a\,$:

$$
(x^2-x+1)^2=4(x^2-x) \;\;\iff\;\; (x^2 - x - 1)^2 = 0 \tag{4}
$$

Since the RHS of $(1)$ is positive, the only qualifying root $x \gt 0$ of $(4)$ is $\;x = \cfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt {g(x)}\ge 0$.  Always! This is the way the square root operation is defined.

If $\sqrt {x - \frac 1x} + \sqrt {1 - \frac 1x} =0$
then $x - \frac 1x = 0$ and $1 - \frac 1x = 0$

Comment: Is there a reason why the equation under the radical equals the sum?

In other words, why does   $x-\frac 1x$ equal zero? Did you take the square root of both sides?

Comment: No, I think you missed my point.  $\sqrt {x - \frac 1x} \ge 0$ and $\sqrt {1 - \frac 1x} \ge 0$ by the definition of square roots.  If $\sqrt {x - \frac 1x} + \sqrt {1 - \frac 1x} =0$ then both $\sqrt {x - \frac 1x}$ and $\sqrt {1 - \frac 1x} =0$ because if either is greater than 0, then the sum cannot equal 0.  Finally, if $\sqrt {1 - \frac 1x} =0$ then $1 - \frac 1x =0$

Comment: Ah okay I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside questions of choice of square roots, the only way $x - 1/x$ can be equal to $1 - 1/x$ is $x=1$.